# How to use mockito for implement dummy?

Tags: junit, mockito

I have simple code:

```
public interface AccountService {
    public boolean verifyBalance(AccountInfo account);
}


public class MoneyTransferServiceBean implements MoneyTransferService {
    private AccountService accountService;

    class MoneyTransfer {
        private TransferRequest request;
        public MoneyTransfer(TransferRequest request) {
            this.request = request;
        }

        private void verifySrcBalance() throws TransferException {
            if (!accountService.verifyBalance("request")
                throw new TransferException("LOW_BALANCE_ERROR_MESSAGE");
        }

    }
}
```

How Im make implement dummy for accountService.verifyBalance()

Im trying this:

```
private MoneyTransferServiceBean moneyTransferService;
AccountService mockedAccountService = mock(AccountService.class);
doReturn(true).when(mockedAccountService).verifyBalance("request");
MoneyTransfer moneyTransfer = moneyTransferService.new MoneyTransfer(transferRequest);
moneyTransfer.verifySrcBalance();
```

But this does not take effect.

Answer (score 2):

generaly doX() methods are used for mocking exception throws and void methods.
Other use is mocked by when([method_call]).thenX();
First create mocks and put your mock into tested service with setters or Whitebox:

```
MoneyTransferServiceBean moneyTransferService = new MoneyTransferServiceBean();
AccountService mockedAccountService = mock(AccountService.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(moneyTransferService , "accountService", mockedAccountService);
```

You should mock interaction with the mock like this:

```
when(mockedAccountService.verifyBalance(eq(accInfo)).thenReturn(true);
verify(mockedAccountService).verifyBalance(accInfo);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedAccountService);
```

There are nice examples on Mockito site explaining it all.